# Renaming the result of QGIS Processing Algorithm

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, rename

When calling a `QgsAlgorithm` from within another, the result will be named after this algorithm output regardless of what is setup as the output of the main one.

For instance, taking the code from [the answer to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327021/clip-the-result-of-my-qgis-3-x-processing-python-script-before-returning-the-out), although the output is set with the name `'OUTPUT'` and the returned `dictionary` is the following:

```
{'OUTPUT': 'clipped_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

the output layer is actually named `'clipped'` and I cannot seem to be able to change this.

I've tried the `setName()` method on the `QgsVectorLayer` retrieved with `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()` but to no avail.

Comment: You should look at this post: [Getting the output layer reference returned by Processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/278061/29431).

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Thanks but as I said below, I'd rather have my algorithm applying a proper name to its output, than to have to run some more code afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the layer from the layer id:

```
output=processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:intersection",params)
createdlayer=QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(output['OUTPUT'])
createdlayer.setName('My shiny new beautiful layer')
```

Comment: So I'd need to run this code after having run my algorithm, right ? I'd really like to have the layer properly named by the algorithm itself rather than having to apply cosmetics afterwards. Or do I understand wrong ?

Comment: You understand right. - at least I have not found any other way of doing it - rather than even more kludgy things like searching for the layer by name. Just to be clear, the first step runs the algorithm (Which in my case is qgis:intersection), this is what I do in a plugin, it may not apply at all to what you are doing...

Comment: Makes sense in the context of a plugin. With my simple algorithm script it seems I'm kind of stuck though. Thanks anyway

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be an actual path on your machine.

For example
`{'OUTPUT': '/root/data/clipped.gpkg'}`

Comment: Ok but the algorithm returns a layer id, not a path