# Change Output name in Script - QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-modeler

I exported a model as script using the properly option in QGIS 3.8.
The Script works perfectly, but the output name is changed.

Heres a print of the model:

[image]

I want that the script´s output name, ***from the Processing Toolbox***, be the one that I designed in the  def initAlgorithm section, and not the given default name.

In the model, the output name comes as "output_name"
and in the script, the output name comes as "Reprojected".

Here's the converted Script:

```py
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
    from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
    import processing


    class Rename(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('shapeinput', 'ShapeInput', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output_name', 'output_name', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Reproject Layer
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['shapeinput'],
            'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output_name']
        }
        outputs['ReprojectLayer'] = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output_name'] = outputs['ReprojectLayer']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'rename'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'rename'

    def group(self):
        return 'rename'

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Rename()
```

Comment: This was also asked before: [How to rename the result of a QGIS Processing Algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331330/how-to-rename-the-result-of-a-qgis-processing-algorithm)

Comment: I have got exactly the same problem, any answers yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I recently realized that the shape created has the properties @layer_name.
This is the element that needs to be changed, but I haven't found how to change it by python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution that worked for me, as parameters['Output_name'] is type [QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Processing/QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition.html) with the attribute destinationName, add this line before calling the processing algorithm:

```
parameters['Output_name'].destinationName = 'your_preferred_name'
```

Comment: Hello @Andrson, I came across this solution a few years ago, but I forgot to update it here. It's definitely the best way

Answer (score 1):

If you need change the name of output, you can do it with this:

```
alg_params = {
        'INPUT': parameters['shapeinput'],
        'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:Name_layer'
    }
```

or if you want to save, only do this:

```
path = '/home/shade/Desktop/name_layer.shp' #or something like that

alg_params = {
        'INPUT': parameters['shapeinput'],
        'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
        'OUTPUT': path
    }
```

For example:

I run the next code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

alg_params = {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:Name_layer'
}

result = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', alg_params)

print ('This is the result: {}'.format(result['OUTPUT']))
print ('This is the name of the layer result: {}'.format(result['OUTPUT'].name()))
```

And obtained this:

[image]

Comment: The first option generated no result. But processed OK

Comment: In this case results['Output_name'] saved the qgsvectorlayer, if you need the name, use results['Output_name'].name()

Comment: I got a SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.

Looking at the API, I find the QgsProcessingFeatureBasedAlgorithm, that returns an output name. I'm trying to understand how it works.

Comment: You only need this: results['Output_name'].name() for return the name of the QgsVectorLayer, no more.

Comment: could you please paste the full code on your answer? no matter where I put it, I got an error.

Comment: I pasted an example for you in the answer. I hope this help you

Comment: @JhonGalindo - I think the OP means that if you run the script _from the Processing Toolbox_, the output name is given the default name. Your code works from the Python Console, now test if it works by converting it into a script which you run from the toolbox.

Comment: Exactly! That is what I mean. Results from the toolbox, not from the console.

Comment: thanks @Joseph , I will do it and I will try to show the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

the last step of the script must be executed inside a variable, here called **step1**
so it respects the name entered in the output parameter through the last block

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureSink

import processing

class Model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('vetor', 'vetor', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('exit', 'exit name', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        step1 = processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'DISSOLVE': False,
                'DISTANCE': 10,
                'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                'INPUT': parameters['vetor'],
                'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'SEGMENTS': 5,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        """here the output name is changed"""
        source = step1
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters,'exit',context,source.fields(),source.wkbType(),source.sourceCrs())
        features = source.getFeatures()
        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'rename'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'rename'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Model()
```

Comment: @Rob here´s the solution