# Automating the selection of starting points in calculation of Shortest path (point to layer) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, shortest-path, network-analysis

For a letter drop experiment in Germany, I am using QGIS Network Analysis tools to calculate the shortest distances from letter drop points to surrounding postboxes. Using the ["Shortest path (point to layer)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-layer) tool I am able to do this with a roads network layer and a postboxes layer. However, I have to select the drop points manually each time.

Is there any way to automate the selection of drop points?

Comment: In processing menu > History, you can see the last processing command lines executed. You can after test it directly from the QGIS Python console to verify if it works, and after, do a loop on the layer features (see here : https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-filtering-features/), extract geometry `feat.geometry().x()` for the x coordinate and pass it in the processing code line as parameter.

Comment: You can also right-click on the processing tool and select : "batch process", and compute automatically all the batch for each points of the letter drop layer.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the PyQGIS.

Let's assume there are three layers, see the image below:

- start points : three red dots in the *'random_points_test'* layer
- end points : three blue dots in the *'points_test'* layer
- a network : 16 features in the *'lines_test2'* layer

[image: input]

Firstly it is important to understand the format of the starting point as an input in the geoalgorithm. To achieve this, use the following command `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:shortestpathpointtolayer")` in the Python Console. This command is also useful to get more information about the geoalgorithm ["Shortest path (point to layer)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-layer) parameters.

```
START_POINT: Start point

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterPoint

    Accepted data types:
        - str: as an 'x,y' string, e.g. '1.5,10.1'
        - QgsPointXY
        - QgsProperty
        - QgsReferencedPointXY
        - QgsGeometry: centroid of geometry is used
```

Secondly, proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor > New Editor` and paste the script below

```py
# Here names of input layers must be specified 
start_points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('random_points_test')[0]
end_points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points_test')[0]
network = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines_test2')[0]

# Looping through all start point features
for feat in start_points.getFeatures():
    start_point_id = feat["id"]
    start_point_geom = feat.geometry()

    parameters = {
        'DEFAULT_DIRECTION' : 2,
        'DEFAULT_SPEED' : 50,
        'DIRECTION_FIELD' : '',
        'END_POINTS' : end_points,
        'INPUT' : network,
        'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
        'SPEED_FIELD' : '',
        'START_POINT' : start_point_geom,
        'STRATEGY' : 0,
        'TOLERANCE' : 0,
        'VALUE_BACKWARD' : '',
        'VALUE_BOTH' : '',
        'VALUE_FORWARD' : ''
        }

    result = processing.run("qgis:shortestpathpointtolayer", parameters)['OUTPUT']
    result.setName(f'Shortest path from point {start_point_id}') # changing the output name
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result) # adding output to the map
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output like this

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Getting layer by name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136861/getting-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis)
- [Getting the output layer reference returned by Processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278061/getting-the-output-layer-reference-returned-by-processing-tool)
- [Renaming the result of QGIS Processing Algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331330/renaming-the-result-of-qgis-processing-algorithm)
- [Rename layers with PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140749/rename-layers-with-pyqgis-script)
- [Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings | PyQGIS 101: Creating & editing a new vector layer](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/)
- [Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings | PyQGIS 101: Filtering features](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-filtering-features/)