# Dynamically naming the resulting temporary layers from the PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am reprojecting a list of files using a for loop

Piece of code:

```
projection = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer',
    {'INPUT' : inputfile,
    'OUTPUT' : 'memory:',
    'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
    })
```

Here, `'OUTPUT':'memory:'` names all reprojected layers as `'output'` which creates confusion. I need each temporary output to be named unique(example: `inputfile_name_reprojected`).

How can I do that?

Being a beginner, I tried all possible scenarios but nothing worked for me.

Comment: A nice question! I was wondering about the same thing when wrote [my answer to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423883/automating-the-selection-of-starting-points-in-calculation-of-shortest-path-poi/424118#424118), where I did it with the `result.setName()` method. As far as I understood from one PyQGIS guru in his answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280468/99589): **it is not straightforward**. @KadirŞahbaz, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to directly set a name within `OUTPUT`, like:

```py
projection = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer',
{'INPUT' : inputfile,
'OUTPUT' : 'memory:{}'.format(inputfile.name()+'_reprojected'),
'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
})
```

Comment: Does this approach also work with `.runAndLoadResults()`?

Comment: @Taras seems like it doesnt. But you can still use `processing.run()` and then `outlayer = projection['OUTPUT']` + `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(outlayer)`

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to use `layer.setName()` within the for loop, like:

```py
for inlayer in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
    projection = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer',
    {'INPUT' : inlayer,
    'OUTPUT' : 'memory:',
    'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
    })
    outlayer = projection['OUTPUT'] # get the output
    outlayer.setName(inlayer.name()+'_reprojected') # rename the output
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(outlayer) # add the output to canvas
```